# Linked iteration inside of objects

Tags: java, iteration

I'm a beginner in programming and I have troubles with linked iteration. If we have usual array like:

```
String[] array = new String[10];
```

...we can iterate by loops based on indexes, I mean, we can create a `for` loop:

```
for(int index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
//some action
}
```

But if we have an object with a reference to another object? For example:

```
public class Node {

    private int value;

    private Node next;

    public Node(int value, Node next) {
        this.value = value;
        this.next = next;
    }

    public int sum(Node start) {
        return start.value + start.next.value + start.next.next.value + start.next.next.next.value;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Node node4 = new Node(1, null);
        Node node3 = new Node(1, node4);
        Node node2 = new Node(1, node3);
        Node node1 = new Node(1, node2);

       System.out.print(new Node(0, null).sum(node1));
    }
}
```

In this code I have a very bad method, trying to calculate summ of all `value` fields of all `Nodes`. Undoubtedly, we need an iteration in `sum(Node start)`, but how to realize that if there is a reference instead of index?

Comment: implement an `Iterator` and use it in an for each loop (oh, just read you are a beginner, I will provide an answer for this)

Comment: You may want to look into recursion

Comment: calculate the sum using while(node.next != null) logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in my comment I would provide an iterator and use a for each loop to iterate over it. This might seem too much efford for a simple task like this, but it will make your future work much easier.

The basic idea is: You implement the interface [Iterator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) to allow iterating over your nodes. Then you let `Node` implement [Iterable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) to allow the use of a for each statement on your nodes. The complete code would look similar to this:

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class Node implements Iterable<Node> {

    class NodeIterator implements Iterator<Node> {

        private Node node;

        public NodeIterator(Node node) {
            this.node = node;
        }

        public boolean hasNext() {
            return node != null;
        }

        public Node next() {
            if (!hasNext())
                throw new NoSuchElementException();
            Node rtn = node;
            node = node.next;
            return rtn;
        }

    }

    private int value;

    private Node next;

    public Node(int value, Node next) {
        this.value = value;
        this.next = next;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<Node> iterator() {
        return new NodeIterator(this);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Node node4 = new Node(1, null);
        Node node3 = new Node(1, node4);
        Node node2 = new Node(1, node3);
        Node node1 = new Node(1, node2);
        int sum = 0;
        for (Node node : node1) {
            sum += node.value;
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

Ask if I should provide more information about iterators (or simply google it). Also, the concept you use is called 'Linked List', search for this for further information.

Answer (score 1):

**One way to do it is using a simple while loop.**

```
public int sum(Node start) {
    Node temp = start;
    int result = 0;
    while(temp != null){
       result += temp.value;
       temp = temp.next;
    }
    return result;
}
```

**another way to do it:**

```
public int sum(Node start){
    int result = 0;
    for(Node temp = start; temp != null; temp = temp.next) result += temp.value;
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need iteration you just sum up `value + next.sum()` so th next node will return `value + next.sum()` and so go on....

But you have to verify if the next reference exists before.

So  you method sum will look lke this :

```
public int sum() {
    return value + (next != null ? next.sum() : 0)
}
```

Comment: shouldn't there be paranthesis around your `?` statement?

Comment: (1) `=!` is not valid Java code. (2) Don't use ternaries in answers to people who are beginners; expand everything. At the very least, explain it. (3) Explain what recursion is; don't just passingly explain it in this instance.